# I can´t separate Data and Time in a DataGridView Column

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datagridview

I have a report, this report has a format of numbers and letters separated for tabs, my intention is separate the data and post it in a `DataGridView`. I want the columns `2`, `6` and `9` - this is already done (Commented). The last column is a `dateTime`, with that `dateTime`, I want separate `Date` and `Time` in 2 columns. I've tried all day, but I don't have a result. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? See my code below.
The result it always gives me is that it shows me the normal and complete datetime in that column,don´t change never...

```
  private void btnCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Button_Click
            {
                var rows = new List<Row>();
                var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\INFT8\Desktop\reportes\prueba2.txt");
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string s = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()))
                    {
                        rows.Add(new Row(s));
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = rows;

            //This method is for load a txt file inside a DataGridView

        }

        public class Row //I find this code for load data from txt file with withespaces
                         // in gridView  since here, equals than the code above.
        {

            public int nroEmp { get; set; }
            public string IngrEgr { get; set; }
            public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

            public Row(string str)
            {
                string[] separator = { "\t" };
                var arr = str.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
                nroEmp = Convert.ToInt32(arr[2]);
                IngrEgr = arr[6];
                Fecha =Convert.ToDateTime( arr[9]); //This [numbers] is the columns that I want show
//To here
                if (IngrEgr == "DutyOn")  //This is for change a data
                    IngrEgr = "Entrada";
                else
                    IngrEgr = "Salida";

                string fec = Fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                string hor = Fecha.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

                var pant = Form.ActiveForm as Form1; //This is for use a form objects
                pant.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column", "Test"); //Add a column
                for (int i = 0; i < pant.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) // i did this loop for 
                                                                        //replace for fec and hor format.
                {
                    pant.dataGridView1[2, i].Value = fec;
                    pant.dataGridView1[3, i].Value = hor;
                }


            }


        }
```

Comment: I try with Fecha.ToShortDateString(); instead of Fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); and nothing

Comment: Your DGV is using a DataTable as the source.  So add the two new columns to the DataTable instead of the DGV.

Comment: @jdweng you know, i use "rows" how DataSource, and rows is a list, no a DataTable :/

Comment: Add to you class ROW two new properties for date and time.

Comment: @jdweng thank you so much! Now it works!